# "Craft Isn’t Installed Yet" Error - Asset Indexes

Tags: error-message, craft4

I have a Craft 4 site — all working fine.

If I go to Utilities > Asset Indexes > Update Asset Indexes, I get the following error:

"Craft isn’t installed yet."

Clearly, this is not the correct error message because I’m getting it inside the Craft dashboard.

If I click 'OK' it carries on updating the asset indexes, only for the error to pop up again a few images later. (With a few hundred images, I have to click 'OK' a dozen times or so to complete the process.)

As far as I can tell, the asset indexing does get completed properly, so it’s more of an irritation than anything, but I’m concerned that it is a symptom of a problem I haven’t spotted.

Note: the error doesn’t appear locally, just on the staging space.

Also note: I have two other Craft sites with the same host, that don’t display the error, so if something’s wrong it’s probably something I did.

Questions:

1. How can I track down the actual error, given that the message is clearly incorrect?
2. Is it a problem, or (considering how infrequently I will use that function post-launch) can I safely ignore it?

Many thanks

Comment: Huh... any errors in Craft's or your web server's logs when that happens?

Comment: storage/logs/web-2022-12-20.log says "2022-12-20 23:30:46 [web.WARNING] [craft\elements\db\ElementQuery::prepare] Element query executed before Craft is fully initialized. {"memory":26063232} 
2022-12-20 23:30:46 [web.WARNING] [application] Request context: {"userId":1,"body":"{\"cacheImages\":true,\"volumes\":[\"*\"]}","vars":{"_GET":{"p":"wddedit/actions/asset-indexes/start-indexing","v":"1671579044873"},"_COOKIE":" and a bunch more stuff.